# Why 'onpaste' event does not work in Iframe with designmode="on"?

Tags: javascript, iframe, prototypejs, onpaste

In FireFox, I use this and it works properly,

```
Event.observe(iFramWin,"paste",tableAlignmentFix);
```

where `iFramWin=$("id").contentWindow;`

and in IE,

```
Event.observe(iFramDoc,"paste",tableAlignmentFix);
```

where `iFramDoc =$("id").contentWindow.document;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MSIE there is no onpaste-event applied to [document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531073%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), observe the onpaste of **document.body** instead.

Example should work in both browsers(also webkit ) :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.0.0/prototype.js"></script>
<script>
function tableAlignmentFix()
{
  alert("tableAlignmentFix:you've pasted something");
}

function init(o)
{ 
  var doc=o.contentWindow.document;
  if(doc.getElementsByTagName('body').length)
  {
    Event.observe(doc.body,"paste",tableAlignmentFix);
    doc.designMode='on';
  }  
}

</script>
<iframe onload="init(this);" src="about:blank" width="200" height"200"></iframe>
```

Comment: +1. This is correct. The `paste` event does bubble in IE but does not bubble any further than the `<body>` element.